# Al Dhabi Lounge (Plaza Premium lounge) Abu Dhabi breakfast at around 6:30 am?

Tags: airports, lounges, abu-dhabi

Will there be food/breakfast at Al Dhabi in early morning? I hear the snacks are all day but breakfast has particular timings.

Comment: There is some info here referring to all-day dining http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/media-centre/press-releases/2017/28-1-2018-Refurbished-Plaza-Premium-Lounge--Al-Dhabi-Now-Opens-at-Abu-Dhabi-International-Airport.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to my email about service hours of the hot buffet, Operation Manager Walid replied:

- Breakfast from 0530 hrs to 1030 hrs
- Lunch from 1100 hrs to 1730 hrs
- Dinner from 1800 hrs to 0300 hrs
- Snacks are available all time